# sonarqube class path problems on linux

Tags: linux, sonarqube

I've been testing SonarQube on my local machine (Windows 7) and both sonar-runner and the Eclipse plugin worked fine.
I had to define sonar.libraries but that was all.

Now I've moved Sonar to a linux server and suddenly I get loads of Class not found errors.
The properties file is still the same, but for some reason Sonar cannot find all the jars.
Moreover, it is complaining about org.dom4j that is not even used in the project.

Any idea?

Comment: There can be only one reason: the value of your sonar.libraries property is incorrect. Feel free to provide a sample project to reproduce the issue locally if you're sure that this is a bug.

Comment: Comes out is a bug with the latest version (2.3) of the Java plugin: http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Unable-to-create-symbol-table-for-xxx-java-tp5026347p5026368.html